# SQL get the value of a nested key in a jsonb field

Tags: sql, json, key, jsonb

Let's suppose I have a table `my_table` with a field named `data`, of type jsonb, which thus contains a json data structure.

let's suppose that if I run

```
select id, data from my_table where id=10;
```

I get

```
 id |                                     data
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 10 | { 
    |"key_1": "value_1" ,
    |"key_2": ["value_list_element_1", "value_list_element_2", "value_list_element_3" ],
    |"key_3": {
    |          "key_3_1": "value_3_1", 
    |          "key_3_2": {"key_3_2_1": "value_3_2_1", "key_3_2_2": "value_3_2_2"}, 
    |          "key_3_3": "value_3_3" 
    |          }
    | }
```

so in pretty formatting, the content of column `data` is

```
{
  "key_1": "value_1",
  "key_2": [
    "value_list_element_1",
    "value_list_element_2",
    "value_list_element_3"
  ],
  "key_3": {
    "key_3_1": "value_3_1",
    "key_3_2": {
      "key_3_2_1": "value_3_2_1",
      "key_3_2_2": "value_3_2_2"
    },
    "key_3_3": "value_3_3"
  }
}
```

I know that If I want to get directly in a column the value of a key (of "level 1") of the json, I can do it with the `->>` operator.

For example, if I want to get the value of `key_2`, what I do is

```
select id, data->>'key_2' alias_for_key_2 from my_table where id=10;
```

which returns

```
 id |                                alias_for_key_2
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 10 |["value_list_element_1", "value_list_element_2", "value_list_element_3" ]
```

Now let's suppose I want to get the value of `key_3_2_1`, that is `value_3_2_1`.

How can I do it?

I have tryed with

```
select id, data->>'key_3'->>'key_3_2'->>'key_3_2_1' alias_for_key_3_2_1 from my_table where id=10;
```

but I get

```
select id, data->>'key_3'->>'key_3_2'->>'key_3_2_1' alias_for_key_3_2_1 from my_table where id=10;
                         ^
HINT:  No operators found with name and argument types provided. Types may need to be converted explicitly.
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in the query

```
select id, data->>'key_3'->>'key_3_2'->>'key_3_2_1' alias_for_key_3_2_1   --this is wrong!
from my_table 
where id=10;
```

was that by using the `->>` operand I was turning a json to a string, so that with the next `->>` operand I was trying to get a json key object `key_3_2` out of a string object, which makes no sense.

Thus one has to use the `->` operand, which does not convert json into string, until one gets to the "final" key.

so the query I was looking for was

```
select id, data->'key_3'->'key_3_2'->>'key_3_2_1' alias_for_key_3_2_1  --final ->> : this gets the value of 'key_3_2_1' as string
from my_table 
where id=10;
```

or either

```
select id, data->'key_3'->'key_3_2'->'key_3_2_1' alias_for_key_3_2_1  --final -> : this gets the value of 'key_3_2_1' as json / jsonb
from my_table 
where id=10;
```

More info on JSON Functions and Operators can be find [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-json.html)